# Spring Boot Data Rest don't support reactive?

Tags: java, spring, rest, reactive-programming, spring-data-rest

So, that error got in log

```
ERROR 15340 --- [nio-8086-exec-9] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler : 
reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly cannot be cast to java.lang.Iterable
```

Create a project by spring initialize: Reactive web, data-rest, data-rest-hal-browser, reactive-mongodb. When i try using data-rest router's i got error. In my opinion that happen, cuz data-rest don't support reactive. Can someone told how fix that?

Comment: What is your code? `FluxOnAssembly cannot be cast to java.lang.Iterable` sounds like you're doing something wrong

Comment: I just use `ReactiveMongoRepository. And when i using standart data-rest  routes, i got that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No yet, see the ticket [[DATAREST-933]](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-933)